# Are iterations and a salt necessary when using random password with PBEKeySpec?

Tags: java, security, encryption

If I use a secure random password as input for a `PBEKeySpec`, does it add value to iterate more than once and add a salt? It does not become more random because of that, right?

Answer (score 0):

If the password is a sequence of random bytes and the correct length there is no need to use PBKDF2.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation!

Comment: That shifts the security of your password from PBKDF2 to whatever RNG you use to generate the password.  Make sure the RNG is at least as secure as PBKDF2, otherwise you will lose security.